# Views - load a node inside a tooltip based on the node's url path

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, tooltip

Is there a way in Drupal Views to load a node inside a tooltip based on the node's url path?

It would be similar to how colorbox node loads content based simply on the class and the path of the node. So for instance:

```
<a href="/node/62" class="colorbox-node">[title]</a>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: loading a node inside a tooltip must be an ajax call or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't matter. Just as long as I can use the node's url path to determine what should be loaded in the tooltip. Thanks Aboodred1